# Pass props from child component to Vue JS page and use @blur/@focus function to call on the prop inside the parent

Tags: typescript, vue.js

looking for some assistance regarding props in Vue JS. I'm quite new to Vue so hopefully I make myself clear in my question.

I've added my code in the snippet below but it does not work because I haven't added the necessary Vue files.

I'm attempting to use a prop that has been created in the DiscountComponentShared.vue file and I would like to use this prop inside the CartPage.vue to bind a class of 'disabled' if the promo code input is clicked on. I would rather like to use @blur and @focus to bind my logic but am unsure how. So currently I hooked it up with an @click. So when a user clicks on the input it will tell  that it is disabled and bind the classs 'disabled'.

```html
//CartPage.vue
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter promo code here" @click="togglePromoCodeInput()" />

<app-one-discount :class="{'moreInfo': showMoreInfo, 'disabled': isDisabled}" :discount-list-disabled="isDisabled">
  <template slot="moreInfoText">
      Minimum purchase of $5. Valid for 3 orders.
      Valid until 24 August 2018 Minimum purchase of $5.
  </template>

  <button class="moreInfoBtn font-italic font-12 text-teal mt-15" @click="toggleMoreInfo" slot="moreInfoBtn">{{ moreInfoBtn }}</button>
</app-one-discount>

<script lang="ts">
  import {
    Vue,
    Component,
    Prop
  } from 'vue-property-decorator';
  import OneDiscount from '../../components/shared/DiscountComponentShared.vue';

  @Component({
    components: {
      appOneDiscount: OneDiscount
    }
  })

  export default class CartPage extends Vue {
    isDisabled: boolean = true;

    togglePromoCodeInput() {
      this.isDisabled = !this.isDisabled;
    }
  }
</script>

//DiscountComponentShared.vue
<template>
    <div class="oneDiscount d-flex justify-content-between">
        <div class="discountAmountBox d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <p class="text-teal font-20">$50 OFF</p>
        </div>

        <div class="discountInfo d-flex align-items-center flex-wrap">
            <div>
                <p class="text-black font-18 font-weight-bold mb-5">Discount Name</p>

                <div class="discountText text-black font-12">
                        <slot name="moreInfoText"></slot>
                </div>

                <slot name="moreInfoBtn"></slot>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
  import {
    Vue,
    Component
  } from 'vue-property-decorator';

  @Component
  export default class DiscountComponentShared extends Vue {
    props!: {
      discountListDisabled: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Not sure I understand. You want the appOneDiscount component to not be shown if someone enters a promo code in the input at the top of CartPage.vue?

Comment: @Andrew1325 Hi Andrew, no i would still like the appOneDiscount to be shown but i would like to bind the 'disabled' class to it so i can style the appOneDiscount component to become greyed out

Comment: it looks ok, so what do you need props for?

Comment: Props only work downwards. In the code you shared, the cart is the parent of the discount component, so cart can share data with the discount component. If you want to share information back from the discount component to the cart component you have to use events. To be honest though, you may be better off using a Vuex store. As for the question: You don't seem to use `discountListDisabled` in your discount component. The cart component defines `isDisabled` differently from what I am used to, but this may be a typescript thing. Other than that I would expect `discountListDisabled` to be a bool

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed my own issue. Because I am using the vue-property-decorator, i need to call props as @prop()

i also used @focus and @blur events to call on the discDisabled data property.

thanks everyone for trying to assist me!

hope this helps someone in future.

```html
//CartPage.vue
<input type="text" :placeholder="placeholder" @focus="promoInputFocused" @blur="promoInputBlurred" class="discountInput w-100 font-16 font-weight-light text-grey86 mb-20" v-model="hasDiscountCode" />

<one-discount :class="{'moreInfo': showMoreInfo, 'active': discount[key]}" :isDisabled="discDisabled">
  <template slot="discountName">{{discount.name}}</template>

  <template slot="moreInfoText">{{ discount.description }}</template>

  <button class="moreInfoBtn font-italic font-12 text-teal mt-15" @click="toggleMoreInfo" slot="moreInfoBtn">{{ discount.moreInfoBtn }}</button>
</one-discount>

<script lang="ts">
  import {
    Vue,
    Component
  } from 'vue-property-decorator';
  import OneDiscount from '../../components/shared/DiscountComponentShared.vue';

  @Component({
    components: {
      appOneDiscount: OneDiscount
    }
  })

  export default class CartPage extends Vue {
    placeholder: string = 'Enter promo code here';
    discDisabled: boolean = false;

    promoInputFocused() {
      this.placeholder = '';

      this.discDisabled = true;
    }

    promoInputBlurred() {
      this.placeholder = 'Enter promo code here';

      this.discDisabled = false;
    }
  }
</script>

//DiscountComponentShared.vue
<template>
        <div class="oneDiscount d-flex justify-content-between" :class="{'disabled': isDisabled}">
            <div class="discountAmountBox d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
                <p class="text-teal font-20">$50 OFF</p>
            </div>
    
            <div class="discountInfo d-flex align-items-center flex-wrap">
                <div>
                    <p class="text-black font-18 font-weight-bold mb-5">Discount Name</p>
    
                    <div class="discountText text-black font-12">
                            <slot name="moreInfoText"></slot>
                    </div>
    
                    <slot name="moreInfoBtn"></slot>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

<script lang="ts">
  import {
    Vue,
    Component,
    Prop
  } from 'vue-property-decorator';

  @Component
  export default class DiscountComponentShared extends Vue {
    @Prop({
      default: false
    }) isDisabled!: Boolean
  }
</script>
```